# How to run a program on the background?

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 monitors, when I open a program on my other monitor and I start using a browser or any other program on the other monitor the 1st program on the other monitor turns grey on the bar and doesn't work any more.

[image: screenshort]

The lower one is working and upper one is not working. I had this problem before but it got fixed by itself.

Comment: I think you're talking about it losing focus, this is the normal behavior in windows, only one window captures input at a time.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot that illustrates this? Take a screenshot, save it, post it anywhere (an image sharing site or a personal web site/blog) and [edit] your question to include a link. Assuming it is legitimate, someone will edit it into the post.

Comment: I don't have 10 rep...
But gyazo here : https://gyazo.com/a4f40405212613a2938e277e80d63052

The lower one is working and upper one is not working.

Comment: What did you want to see (or do) in the first window that is of concern? Whilst working with the second window, what was supposed to happen in the first?

Comment: I want the program to stay as the lower one, because it doesn't work when It's grey like the upper one.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Think about it - the active/inactive indicates which program is taking input from the keyboard and mouse, i.e. which is the *active* program.

I know you have two monitors and you can see two programs at once - but I can do the same on my one screen, can't I? I can resize both windows to fit, or I can run two small windows (say two calculator applications) and they won't be overlapping - but still, only one can be active at a time. Why should it be different just because it's on another monitor?

Let's say they're both word documents. What happens when you start typing? Where should the text go? Only one window can be active at once, it's by design. I can understand if this isn't the answer you wish to hear, but it's the correct answer in this case.